# Flex Combobox and "Access of undefined property ..." error

Tags: apache-flex, combobox

I am kind of puzzled and not sure how to tackle this issue: Got two comboxes with dataproviders. Also, I created a separate index.as in /as folder. I have these two functions:

In my .mxml page, I have :

```
          <mx:FormItem label="Property Code:" id="fi_propertyCode"  width="100%">
                 <mx:ComboBox id="propertyCode"  width="50%" dataProvider="{qry_communites}" change="showPropertyCode()" />
              </mx:FormItem>

               <mx:FormItem label="Utility Type:" id="fi_utilityType" width="100%">
                  <mx:ComboBox id="utilityType"  width="50%" dataProvider="{qry_utilityTypes}" change="showUtilityType()" />
             </mx:FormItem>
```

and in my index.as, I have:

```
private function showPropertyCode():void {
     mx.controls.Alert.show(propertyCode.selectedItem.label, propertyCode.selectedItem.data);
}



private function showUtilityType():void {
    mx.controls.Alert.show(utilityType.selectedItem.label, utilityType.selectedItem.data);
}
```

I get an error saying

Access of undefined property utilityType.

The funny thing is I don't get this error for "propertyCode". Moreover, If I copy pasyte showUtilityType() function and put inside my .mxml page, I don't get this error either. Btw. I have :

```
  ....
```

in my .mxml page. What should I do? How can I get rid of this error? Why does Flex see propertyCode combobox but not utilityType combobox? I would rather keep index.as as it is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the three dots will be : 
    <mx:Script>
      <![CDATA[
       include "../as/index.as";
  ....

Comment: you can edit the post to change the three dots to appropriate text

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. Did you try specifying the script using the source attribute?

```
<mx:Script source="../as/index.as"/>
```

Comment: I tried that as well. I guess I will need to get rid of index.as and put all the actionscript inside my .mxml page.